# Power Series expansion of $\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$ at $z_0 = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I would like to figure out the power series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}$ around $z_0=1$. Somehow expanding this into a geometric series would be the way to go I suppose, however, I fail to see how this can be rearranged in terms of (z-1). Maybe somebody could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\large\textbf{Hint :}$

$$ \frac{1}{\left(1+z\right)^{2}}=\frac{1/4}{\left(1-\frac{1-z}{2}\right)^{2}} $$

Now, how about using the series expansion of $ \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}} $ arround $ 0 $ ?

Answer (score 0):

This adds to the other answer/ hint:

How about the fact that $-(\dfrac 1{1+z})'=\dfrac 1{(1+z)^2}?$

So differentiate $\sum_{n\ge0}(-z)^n$ termwise.

Get $$-\sum_{n\ge0}n(-z)^{n-1}.$$

So, let $w=z-1$.  Get $$\dfrac 1{1+z}=\dfrac 1{2+w}=\dfrac 12\dfrac 1{1-(-\dfrac w2)}.$$

So finally $$-\dfrac 14\sum _{n\ge0}n(-\dfrac w2)^{n-1},$$ or
$$-\dfrac 14\sum _{n\ge0}n(-\dfrac {(z-1)}2)^{n-1}.$$